# Search for sub-string that start with some characters and replace the the whole sub-string with blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
@Mystring = 'We will meet on May-01, May-03, May-08, June-1, June-23 and June-28'.
```

I want to replace all the substring that start with 'May-' with blank ''. I want my result to be:

```
@Mystring = 'We will meet on June-1, June-23 and June-28'.
```

Given that we don't know how many day or what date in May that the full string has. All I know is I need to cancel all the meeting date in May.
thanks.

Comment: (1) You should tag your questions with the database you are using.  (2) Having said that, this is not a very good fit for SQL.

Comment: Your first step should be to determine the scope of your project. How many rows must be updated? If it is a small number, stop wasting time and just update them manually. Writing code, testing it, validating results, and then repeating in the production environment will be quite a lot of work for someone with little experience.

Answer (score 0):

This would work in Postgres to remove all May dates:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('We will meet on May-01, May-03, May-08, June-1, June-23 and June-28'
                    , 'May-\d*,* *'
                    , ''
                    , 'g')
```

Details depend on more information ...